# Why is typescript telling me "Cannot compile external modules unless the --module flag is provided?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am getting Typescript error message indicated in title above.  Included here is one example of what it doesn't like... If I click on the error message it takes me to the I in IGLOBALS definition below.

```
export interface IGlobals {
    HomePageUrl: string;
    loginPageUrl: string;
    TimeOut: number;
    Changed(url: string)
}
```

I am using VS2013 with these settings.  No matter what value I choose for "Module System" I still get this error.  I'm running Version 1.5.0 beta of Typescript (which could be the issue, not sure)...

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in a module...

```
module MyModule{
    export interface IGlobals {
        HomePageUrl: string;
        loginPageUrl: string;
        TimeOut: number;
        Changed(url: string)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon; I'll give that a try today.